The galois group of $p^{k}$-torsions of an elliptic curve defined over a global function field of characteristic $p \ge 5$
I'm looking for an analogy of Corollary 7.5.3 in 『A first course in modular forms』(Diamond and Shurman) over a global function field. The colloary follows:
For the elliptic curve $$
 E: y^{2} = x^{3} - \frac{27j}{4\left(j-1728\right)}x - \frac{27j}{4\left(j-1728\right)}
$$ defined over the function field $\mathbb{Q}\left(j\right)$ and any positive integer $N$, we have $$
 \operatorname{Gal}\left(\frac{\mathbb{Q}\left(j\right)\left(E\left[N\right]\right)}{\mathbb{Q}\left(j\right)}\right) \supseteq  \operatorname{SL}_{2}\left(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}\right).
$$
For a global function field $\mathbb{K}$ of characteristic $p\ge 5$, the analogy what I looking is about the elliptic curve $$
 A: y^{2} = x^{3} - \frac{27j}{4\left(j-1728\right)}x - \frac{27j}{4\left(j-1728\right)}
$$ defined over the function field $\mathbb{K}\left(j\right)$ and any positive integer $k$. I guess that the Galois group $$
 \operatorname{Gal}\left(\frac{\mathbb{K}\left(j\right)\left(A\left[p^{k}\right]\right)}{\mathbb{K}\left(j\right)}\right)
$$ contains the multiplicative group $$
 \left\{ u \in \left(\mathbb{Z}/p^{k}\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\times}: u \equiv 1 \pmod{p} \right\}.
$$
Is my guess right? If my guess were right, would you recommend some references explaining my guess?
